# Disambiguation (or aliasing) of [language] and [languages] tags needed

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

Currently there's a tag [language](/questions/tagged/language) and a tag [languages](/questions/tagged/languages). Both currently have no tag wiki entry. I'm not quite sure what each one of those is good for, on some posts they are used in the context of spoken languages, and on others in the context of a programming language. But for programming languages there's a separate tag.

So, what exactly are they meant to be?

- Are they both for spoken languages? In that case one of them should become an alias for the other one.
- Is one for spoken language and one for programming? In that case a wiki should be added to both, and/or one of them should be made into an alias of the programming-languages tag.

In any case, some questions using those tags need to be re-tagged depending on the meaning they will finally have. I would have suggested wiki edits, but didn't do it since I wasn't sure which was intended to be use for what. Not being a native speaker, it's pretty hard for me to say if any one of them standing for itself is clear enough to distinguish a programming context from a linguistic context.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from questions such as [Difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944774/difference-between-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference), where [language](/questions/tagged/language) is referring to the programming language, and it would not add any meaning to the question, [language](/questions/tagged/language) seems used for localization questions, such as the ones about a localization file used in some frameworks (see [Codeigniter calendar language problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966715/codeigniter-calendar-language-problem)), or other questions related to the language (see [Add a new input language on symbian s60v5 nokia phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958765/add-a-new-input-language-on-symbian-s60v5-nokia-phone)).

This seems also the purpose of [languages](/questions/tagged/languages).
In this case, [language](/questions/tagged/language) could be made a synonym of [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) and the tags merged. Usually it is used the plural word, in a tag; if using the singular makes more sense, then [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) could be made synonym of [language](/questions/tagged/language), and the tags merged.

Comment: _Usually_ we like to use the plural.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. This came to my mind this morning: _language_ as in _bad language_ and _languages_ as in _spoken languages_. Not sure if that distinction is needed within tags though, or if it was ever meant to be used that way.